# Customizing kernel

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I have read and attempted to follow every link for customizing Ubuntu's kernel including:

- [Build Your Own Kernel - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) -# I started with this one and could not continue when I got to the step referencing `fakeroot /debian/rules` because `debian` directory did not exist.
- [Kernel/Compile](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) (last updated 3/5/2013) # Again, don't have `debian` folder
- [What's a simple way to recompile the kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/q/163298/159545)

I get everything downloaded (except for the packages which no longer exist).  But after that, I can't go any further:

I've downloaded source of all kernels for this release:

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git
```

And moved it to the /usr/src/ubuntu-precise directory and although I could not locate or find the debian folder it was under /usr/src/ubuntu-precise/debian. Perhaps because I did not have the symbolic link?

Renamed the older version source directory and created a symbolic link for ubuntu-precise with the same name. This was in a book Ubuntu Unleashed Page 426.

I've downloaded/installed the build environment:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname-r)
```

Following the directions on the [second link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) above, I installed the packages indicated:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-devel fakeroot -kernel-wedge buid-essential
  (linux-kernel devel not found) Removed and continued with others because it is
  supposedly now part of the build-dep linux...etc.
```

this only installed `fakeroot` because all others were there.

Also installed:

```
sudo apt-get install crash kexec-tools makedumpfuile
sudo apt-get build-dep linux      # which did not install or update

sudo apt-get install git-core libncurse5 libncurse5-dev libelf-dev asciidoc binutils-dev
sudo apt-get install kernel-package
sudo apt-get install ccaches
```

and last but not least

```
sudo apt-get install libnewt-dev  # which was already there and did not install
```

Since I had now tried this several times, I had to:

```
$make-kpkg #to clean source directories
$make mrproper # to clean all subdirectories of source
```

restore the .config deleted by mrproper by copying it from `/boot` to `/usr/src/ubuntu-precise`.  From source directory ubuntu-precise:

```
$sudo cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) ./.config # $(uname -r) checks current kernel and grabs it
$ make menuconfig # to open old config, make changes and save
$ fakeroot make-kpkg-j 2 --initrd --append-to-version=-jn kernel_image kernel_headers
```

where 2 = # of processors
and -jn is appended to the deb to notate changed version

It is compiling right now, but I sincerely hope I don't receive an error.  We sincerely need one GOOD set of instructions which instead of saying do this or that, explains what you are doing when you use the command and a wiki should be kept up to date.

Comment: Maybe some of the answers [here can get you on the right path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227754/how-can-i-modify-the-kernel-when-i-already-have-ubuntu-running-on-my-machine/353116)